# Make Docker Compose available to non-root user?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've created a non-root user (`userB`) on my Ubuntu Linux 22.04.4 server for an application and added them as a member of the `docker` group. When I try checking the Docker Compose version as this user, I get an error.

```
$ groups
userB docker
$ docker compose version
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

As my server's main user (`userA`), Docker & Compose both seem to be installed and available with no problems.

```
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.24.6
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           25.0.3
 API version:       1.44
 Go version:        go1.21.6
 Git commit:        4debf41
 Built:             Tue Feb  6 21:13:09 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
```

Just in case the user's groups weren't getting refreshed, I've rebooted the server just to ensure the groups were loaded prpoperly yet I still get the same error. Is there anything else I need to do to make docker compose available to this user?

Comment: In general running docker and containers as non-root requires additional setup. see https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

Comment: Check `docker info` for both users. Also, check `which docker`

Comment: @HBruijn The setup at that page fixed my issue. A lot of the setup on that page are already the "defaults" on the latest LTS Ubuntu release so not much extra was needed on my part but the rootless setuptool shell script needed to be run to complete things. The error message I was getting with docker compose didn't steer me towards that being the problem so I wouldn't have guessed that was the solution. Thanks!

Comment: on debian it might be docker-compose meaned on the old packages which might similar to ubuntus behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in  https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

For each user that will be using rootless docker you need to run a individual setup script `dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install`  to set up the daemon.

```
dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install
[INFO] Creating /home/testuser/.config/systemd/user/docker.service
...
[INFO] Installed docker.service successfully.
[INFO] To control docker.service, run: `systemctl --user (start|stop|restart) docker.service`
[INFO] To run docker.service on system startup, run: `sudo loginctl enable-linger testuser`

[INFO] Make sure the following environment variables are set (or add them to ~/.bashrc):

export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock
```